# SQL with limit by result

Tags: sql, chat

I am making a simple chat, and need a way to get only 10 "messages" pr. conversation, but can't figure out how to do so.

This is what i already have tried.
my SQL:

```
SELECT c.* FROM chat c
INNER JOIN users su ON su.id = c.sender_user_id
INNER JOIN users ru ON ru.id = c.receiver_user_id
WHERE sender_user_id='1234' OR receiver_user_id='1234'
ORDER BY created ASC
```

Now i get ALL the messages for user ID 1234 ... BUT i only want 10 messages pr. conversation.

Hope it make sense

Comment: Do you need a technique that works in standard SQL or you just forgot to tag the question?

Comment: Right.  It is Select top 10 * if MSSQL and LIMIT 10 if MySQL for example.

Comment: Let me join in the fun for Oracle: ....... WHERE rownum() <= 10

Comment: Without seeing the DDLs, it's a little hard to answer definitively, especially as you have (I suspect) two columns called `id` (chat.id and users.id)

Comment: I hope it can be done in MySQL, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

The standard SQL way is to use window/analytic functions:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT c.*, su.name as sender_name, ru.name as receiver_name,
             row_number() over (partition by c.conversation order by c.created desc) as seqnum
      FROM chat c INNER JOIN
           users su
           ON su.id = c.sender_user_id INNER JOIN
           users ru
           ON ru.id = c.receiver_user_id
      WHERE sender_user_id = '1234' OR receiver_user_id = '1234'
     ) t
WHERE seqnum <= 10
ORDER BY created ASC;
```

Note that you need to do a better job of selecting the columns you want in the subquery.  Using `*` will result in duplicate column names.

EDIT:

In MySQL, you can do this using variables:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT c.*, su.name as sender_name, ru.name as receiver_name,
             (@rn := if(@c = c.conversation, @rn + 1,
                        if(@c := c.conversation, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      FROM chat c INNER JOIN
           users su
           ON su.id = c.sender_user_id INNER JOIN
           users ru
           ON ru.id = c.receiver_user_id CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @c := 0, @rn := 0) vars
      WHERE sender_user_id = '1234' OR receiver_user_id = '1234'
      ORDER BY c.conversation, c.created desc
     ) t
WHERE seqnum <= 10
ORDER BY created ASC;
```

Comment: Thanks alot ... but i got this error: syntax to use near '(partition by c.conversation order by c.created desc) as seqnum   ... Any idea?

Comment: Which database are you using? SQL server 2008 does not support this syntax.